# Javascript replace function not working when search pattern contain ? mark

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing an issue with the replace function in javascript.

```
"demo text?for test".replace(new RegExp("text?for", 'g'), "text for");
```

Its return output is  "demo text?for test".

I think, I am missing something but I don't know.

Below is my function I used in my application

```
 var replaceAll = function (targetString, search, replacement) {
            return targetString.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
        };

 replaceAll("This is my favorite video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3MPiLq0fKc", "video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3MPiLq0fKc", "http://d-d.co/4eDED")
```

output is "This is my favorite video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3MPiLq0fKc"

Comment: `?` has special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape that character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, provided you supply the regular expression as a string enclosed in `/` and with the special characters properly escaped, like this:

```js
var replaceAll = function(targetString, search, replacement) {
  return targetString.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

console.log(replaceAll("This is my favorite video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3MPiLq0fKc", /video https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=n3MPiLq0fKc/, "http://d-d.co/4eDED"))
```

Comment: Thanks for response. can we add escape character in text  through any javascript function before replace?

Comment: RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};